# Compute the quadratic residue symbol $\big(\frac{509}{997}\big)$ both are prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Compute the quadratic residue symbol $\big(\frac{509}{997}\big)$ both are prime.

So I found that $509$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$, so I know that $\big(\frac{509}{997}\big)=\big(\frac{997}{509}\big)$.

I tried to compute using $997=509+488$ and then computing $\big(\frac{488}{509}\big)$ but it still doesn't seem something easy to compute by hand.

Comment: same as $(-21| 509)=(-1| 509)(3| 509)(7| 509)$

Comment: @WillJagy So I know $-1$ is a quadratic residue. And I know that the quadratic residues mod $3$ are $1$ and are $1,4,2$ mod $7$. So I guess I just need to find $509$ mod $7$ and mod $3$?

Comment: Alternatively, as $488=2^3\times 61$ then $$\left(\frac{488}{509}\right)=\left(\frac{488}{509}\right)^3\left(\frac{61}{509}\right).$$ As $509\equiv-3\pmod8$ then $\left(\frac{2}{509}\right)=-1$ and $\left(\frac{61}{509}\right)=\left(\frac{509}{61}\right)=\left(\frac{21}{61}\right)$ etc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown:  Did you mean $\left(\dfrac{2}{509}\right)^3$ where you typed $\left(\dfrac{488}{509}\right)^3$?

Comment: The perils of cut-n-paste! Too late to edit the damned thing now .... @J.W.Tanner